# How can I get Output like this in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I need output like this :-

```
ID :- 1
    Hotel :- Hotel 1
    Packages :- 
            Package 1 = 10$
            Package 2 = 20$
            Package 3 = 30$
    
    ID :- 2
    Hotel :- Hotel 2
    Packages :- 
            Package 1 = 10$
            Package 2 = 20$
            Package 3 = 30$
    
    
    
    ID :- 3
    Hotel :- Hotel 3
    Packages :- 
            Package 1 = 10$
            Package 2 = 20$
            Package 3 = 30$
```

After that I want to get input as hotel ID, relevant package, and how many packages customers want. then I need to calculate the full amount.

This is my code;-

But this code's output never fullfill my requirement

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class HotelChainServicePublishImpl implements HotelChainServicePublish {
    
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String[]> hotelList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String[]>();
    Double subTotal = 0.0;
    @Override
    public void getHotels() {
        hotelList.put(1, new String[] {"Hotel 1" , "100000.00"} );
        hotelList.put(2, new String[] {"Hotel 2" , "200000.00"} );
        hotelList.put(3, new String[] {"Hotel 3" , "300000.00"} );
    
        hotelList.forEach((k, v)  -> {System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(k + ")");
        Arrays.asList(v).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the nested indentations whith the phrase "output like this":

you can use the tab character `\t` in order to indent text. For nested indentation you will need to keep track of the indentation level as with each newline the indentation gets reset.

You can then compute a prefix for each line you print with

```
String prefix = "";
for (int i = 0; i < indentation_level; i++) {
    prefix += "\t";
}
```

You may need to pass the indentation level to other functions and/or increase it as needed.